# OPENROWSET equivalent in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, openrowset

I have an Excel file and I want to run a query direct only. In `SQL Server`, we can use `OPENROWSET` for this. From extensive digging, I found that Access can read CSVs from a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\Temp\;].[MyCSV.csv]
```

However, I am unable to tweak the connection for reading from Excel.

Is there equivalent of `OPENROWSET` in MS Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading from an Excel file you need to use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\foo\Book1.xlsx].[Sheet1$];
```